# How to hide some parameter from url in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

My url is like this

> http://www.dezaro.com/index.php/product/156/48/Baskets

and want to change it into

http://www.dezaro.com/Living/Decor/Baskets

here 156 mean Living and 48 is Decor

I also tried to hide index.php but my htaccess code won't work. Here is my code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Making Route might helpful.
[URI Routing](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html)

Comment: i have already tried it ... here us my root                        $route['product/(:any)'] = "product/index/$1";
$route['product'] = "product";

Comment: Then another thing you can do, but it might need a lots of change in your code.

You can post Living and Decor instead of GET through http url.

Comment: so in this case i will not use the id of my category and subcategory

Comment: Siddharth bro, what you are trying to do, it might be possible, but I don't know how to do it. My suggestion would be to use POST method in your product controller where you are receiving your data. It would be lot more easier.

Comment: You have to change your controller (or rather method) code queryng DB table by `Living` string and by `Decor` string instead of `CAT1` and `CAT2` fields that search for `INT` So controller could "know" what typed URL means.